# how to test gunicorn config file syntax

Tags: python, ubuntu, gunicorn

Is there a way in ubuntu or python or a gunicorn function to test if the gunicorn config file syntax is correct.

I am using:

- gunicorn 19.9.0 is installed on the app environment
- python 3.6
- ubuntu 18.04

At this moment the `gunicorn_config.py` is like this:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:8811'
worker_class = 'sync'
loglevel = 'info'
accesslog = '/var/log/gunicorn/access_log_myapp'
errorlog = '/var/log/gunicorn/error_log_myapp'
spew = False
```

And I want to add a few lines to modify the log formats and try different gunicorn config files.

I am not sure how to test the syntax using ubuntu.

I have tryed adding this line to the code:

```
acceslogformat =" JALAZBE TEST %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s %(r)s %(s)s %(b)s %(f)s %(a)s"
```

And it will not write the acces log as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly want.

But, I guess, you probably want to check a config file is valid.

You can try this:

`$ gunicorn --check-config APP_MODULE`

or

`$ gunicorn --check-config config.py`

Of course, You need to name WSGI application object as `application` because default setting of gunicorn has target application as `application`.

You can find a detail solution [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#configuration-overview).

Comment: Changed in version 19.4: Loading the config from a Python module requires the `python:` prefix. https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#settings